# Can't find tikzlibraryarrows.meta.code.tex in TexMaker 4.5

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, shadows}` in TexMaker 4.5 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. It is showing following error-

```
! I can't find file `tikzlibraryarrows.meta.code.tex'.<argument> ...nput tikzlibrary\pgf@temp .code.tex\catcode `\@ =\csname tikz... ...library{arrows.meta, positioning, shadows}
```

I tried to update the texlive distribution. but `tlmgr update --all` is showing `tlmgr: no updates available`.

What is missing here?

Comment: What version of TeX Live do you have? (Look in the first line of the `.log` file.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: The first line is following - `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2016.5.16)  17 MAY 2016 13:28`

Comment: I have TexLive 2015 installed.`PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH`

Comment: Well it doesn't look like the TL2015 installation is picked up, as the log file points to TL2013/Debian. Which is old enough that version 3 of `pgf`, where the `arrows.meta` library was introduced, is not available. I'm not very good with these kinds of things though, when I install TL I usually just follow [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373). Edit: in other words, I don't have any good suggestions for how to fix it.